# Determine all xpath references / xml elements "used" in an XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

**Problem:**

We have a massive XML document. This document gets passed around a bit before eventually ending up being used in an XSLT2 transform which prepares it for use in a PDF rendering engine. The issue is that the percentage of the XML actually needed by the time we get to the PDF rendering engine is tiny compared to its original size. We still need the full XML for other processes, but in terms of the "flow" towards the rendering engine, we ideally would like to strip the XML down to its bare essentials as soon as possible so that the amount of data being passed around is smaller.

We cannot do the final XSLT2 transformation earlier in the process, as there is a little bit more XML manipulation that happens just prior to this.

What we would like to do therefore is create a new stylesheet which simply "keeps" the structure of the original XML document but only keeps the XML elements we're actually interested in for reporting purposes. We're quite happy to write the necessary XSLT document, but since the final XSLT2 document is a complicated beast, what we're hoping is that someone out there in the stackoverflow community has an easy way of doing the following:

**Ideal solution:**

A way of extracting a list of all referenced XML elements (i.e. their xPath) from an existing XSLT2 stylesheet. We'd like this to include referenced XML elements not only in selects/value-ofs/etc., but also in fors/conditions/etc.

I realise this may not have a simple answer, but just in case someone out there has either done this before, or can give me a starting point, I'd be very grateful for any assistance.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: What language (technology stack) do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good luck.  I don't know of any off the shelf solutions.

I can think of two approaches to solving this; both will be very interesting and (in the general case) a lot of work, worth it in this case only if the advantage of thinning the XML down is worth a great deal to you, or if your particular case turns out to be significantly easier than the general case.

1. You can instrument the XSLT stylesheet so that every time any template visits a node, it records the identity of that node (e.g. in the form of a numeric path from the root in the style of a simple XPointer, or possibly in the form of a fully qualified generic identifier (the sequence of element names beginning with the document element and going down to the element being visited).  A second stylesheet can then read that list of nodes visited and make a copy of the input, labeling each node as having been used or not.  Do this for enough input and you will (perhaps) see patterns you can use to thin the XML down.  Do this for enough input and you can have a check to see whether a given thinning process would have (a) missed some things it could drop, or (b) dropped some things it ought not to have dropped.
2. You can try to work abstractly from the stylesheet, starting from the template for the root element and noting which classes of possible elements will match which templates.  It may help your reasoning here if you have a good schema for the input vocabulary and can assume validity against that schema as a premise.

Both of these are very challenging -- the second one looks a lot like the kind of thing type theorists try to do to enable one to predict in advance whether the output from a given XSLT transformation will or won't be valid against a particular output, given valid input.  And unfortunately the short summary of that work to date appears to be "Gosh, that's hard!"  On the other hand, your task is a little simpler than theirs:  all you want to know is, can you tell in advance by looking at the transformation that particular branches in an XML document will never affect the output of the transformation?  And you don't have to solve it for the general case, you only have to solve it for one particular transformation.

Comment: In the end, time pressures have meant we forget about a nice and neat "automatic" approach and have gone the route of "hand cranking" the XSLT we need. Luckily we have a large set of tests to verify that we've caught all of the nodes we're interested in. But if anyone does find a solution, I'd still love to hear it. Marking the above as answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an XSLT stylesheet that copies whatever available to a new document in exactly the same structure as before, skipping only those tags considered to be redundant.

The following stylesheet does exactly this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <html><textarea rows="20" cols="120">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
       </textarea></html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="removeElmt1|removeElmt2|@removeAttr1|@removeAttr2">
   <!-- do nothing :) -->
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation: never forget that XSLT is not a programming language, but a specification for a transformation engine.

The first template specifies to start the process, the second template specifies to match on everything and then to copy everything, except for the elements and attributes specified in the third template.

> Note: If elements or attributes are reused in the document then more
>   specific Xpath statements are required in the 'match' specification of
>   the third template, in order to delete only those specified.

The first template contains two redundant specifications for the result to be readable in a browser. For the exact copy you need to remove the `<html>` and `<textarea>` specification elements, and set the output method to XML.

Comment: I don't think you have read the question carefully enough (despite having more than 2 years to do so...).

Comment: @michael.hor257k: "What we would like to do therefore is create a new stylesheet which simply 'keeps' the structure of the original XML document but only keeps the XML elements we're actually interested in for reporting purposes." and "if anyone does find a solution, I'd still love to hear it".

Comment: Right. Except that there is no given list of "the XML elements we're actually interested in". Instead, they were hoping to find a "way of extracting a list of all referenced XML elements (i.e. their xPath) **from an existing XSLT2 stylesheet**". Otherwise the problem would be trivial (and you would think that [one of the authors of the XML specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Sperberg-McQueen) would know enough to provide the equally trivial solution).

Comment: BTW, your solution actually presumes a list of "the XML elements we're **not** interested in".

Answer (score 0):

A late addition: what's described here sounds very like "document projection" which is a technology that's available in a number of XQuery processors (including Saxon). XQuery is more amenable to static analysis than XSLT (because it lacks the very dynamic template despatch mechanism).

Document projection takes a document and a query as input, and produces as output a document containing only those parts of the original document that are needed to answer the original query. The benefit is that the document projection process is streamed - the original document does not need to be built in memory; instead the projection process acts as a filter for the events coming from the XML parser.

The original theory is described here: Amelie Marian, Jerome Simeon, 2003, Projecting XML Documents, Columbia University Academic Commons, http://hdl.handle.net/10022/AC:P:29177.